# Scala DBs? Relational algebra?

Tags: database, scala

Are there databases written in Scala, or particularly effective use of Scala capabilities?

Has anyone implemented the relational algebra, or Tutorial D, in Scala?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a NoSQL variant called [Treode.](https://www.treode.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the closest thing to an answer that I have found.

```
 www.scala-lang.org/node/6539

 http://code.google.com/p/orbroker/
```

It's not a complete database, but orbroker does provide a Scala-specific interface to relational databases.